How to show debug logs while running blazor hybrid app on local android device?
I am using VS2022 Community Edition on Windows 10. I have followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/device/setup?view=net-maui-8.0 and have gotten my blazor hybrid project in C# to run on my local device but I don't know how to show debug logs, something like Console.Writeline to troubleshoot stuff.

maybe you could try write logs to file.
